Regex pattern to match contents of specific HTML <script> tag
Consider the following HTML snippet:
[arbitrary content]

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = {
        "locale": "fr-FR",
        "env": "production"
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.dataLayer = [{
        "event": "data-layer-loaded",
        [...]
    }];
</script>

[more arbitrary content]

I'm trying to isolate specifically the hash defined as window.__PRELOADED_STATE__, i.e. the following content:
{
   "locale": "fr-FR",
   "env": "production"
}

For some reason, the following pattern does not seem to get a match:
/<script type="text\/javascript">window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.*?);<\/script>/
(in this case the result would be in group 1, but regex groups are not a requirement)
Does anybody have a better suggestion? For what it's worth, the above is intended for a vanilla ruby 3.3 context (not rails). Besides, the source content contains dozens of scripts, so matching any script would not be sufficient.
Any input would be most welcome!

This is really a 2 part thing; you need to parse the html to pull out the JS, then you need to parse the JS to pull out the value you want.  For the first part an html parser is far better than a regex.

@erik258 both questions are only similar insofar as they pertain to the parsing of an HTML document in Ruby. But they're certainly not identical: the other one concerns HTML parsing in general, while the one here is specifically about a regex pattern. Case in point: my script will run in a Docker image on a Synology NAS, so loading Nokogiri or Oga would be overkill (if not outright impossible) when using a correct regex pattern would achieve the desired result.

<script type="text\/javascript">\s*window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ =\s*\K\{[^}]+\} should be possible in Oniguruma and Onigmo  afaik

@DuesserBaest It works beautifully: many thanks for your suggestion! Regex keeps being a mystery for me...

@erik258 Please stop marking this question as a duplicate; it's not. The other one does not even contain any reference to regex. Besides, DuesserBaest's answer solves the issue at stake here, but it would have been irrelevant in the context of the other question. I don't see why you keep insisting.

I agree with @erik258's approach.  would recommend a combination of html parser and regex. Example
